# In altair: how to assign individual placements to selection elements (dropdown lists etc) in a concatenated plot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, selection, altair, vega-lite

This is a follow up question to: [On an Altair plot, can you change the location that a selection (e.g. dropdown, radio button) is displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59025953/on-an-altair-plot-can-you-change-the-location-that-a-selection-e-g-dropdown)

I have the situation, that I've got a horizontally concatenated chart, where I use a dropdown selector for the left and another one for the right plot. Now I would like either list to appear underneath their respective plot.

Currently they both appear on top of each other, and with the solution from the link above I can move them together from left to right. Is there a way to separate them?

I don't know whether that's something altair can do, i.e. whether the preconditions in vega-lite allow for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you might do this is to use the same strategy as the linked question, but with the [Subsequent Sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) in CSS. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

input_dropdown1 = alt.binding_select(options=['Europe','Japan','USA'], name='chart1')
selection1 = alt.selection_single(fields=['Origin'], bind=input_dropdown1)

chart1 = alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color = alt.condition(selection1, 'Origin:N', alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip='Name:N'
).add_selection(
    selection1
)

input_dropdown2 = alt.binding_select(options=['Europe','Japan','USA'], name='chart2')
selection2 = alt.selection_single(fields=['Origin'], bind=input_dropdown2)

chart2 = alt.Chart(data.cars.url).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q',
    color = alt.condition(selection2, 'Origin:N', alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip='Name:N'
).add_selection(
    selection2
)

from IPython.display import HTML
display(HTML("""
<style>
.vega-bind {
  text-align:right;
}
.vega-bind ~ .vega-bind {
  text-align:left;
}
</style>
"""))
display(chart1 | chart2)
```

[image]

Comment: yes that works!
however, so far I can only get it to align left | right when I use the display(...) method as shown in the answer.
I need to also save it to html. But when I do alt.hconcat(cart1, cart2).save('figure.html') the alignment of dropdown boxes is not saved.